# Pip installing not working

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
```

gives me an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

So I go to cmd and typed `pip install matplotlib` but I get 'Requirement already satisfied'.

I am not really sure what to do....

Comment: what version of python are you using to run your code? I men how are you running your code.

Comment: Just checking, are you sure you installed it for the correct version of Python?

Comment: quite simply you are mixing wrong python versions or wrong virtualenvs

Comment: Hi, I am using Pycharm and I believe the version is 3.5

Comment: so if I were to remove old versions then it should work?

Comment: no i only have 3.5 on my computer..

Comment: I suppose you are running this code in an IDE that is in a different virtual enviroment where matplotlib is installed

Comment: Sorry and thank you. I solved the problem. I was doing 'pip install matplotlib' in a different directory. For some reason, I had two different directories 'Scripts', one of which contains pip and the other doesnt.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information you have provided. Go to PyCharm Preferences. Then go to `Project:your-project-name`, inside this to `Project Interpreter`.
[image]

and make sure this interpreter has installed `matplotlib`. Othersiwe, click on the `+` sign and add the library you need.[image]

Comment: Nice nice nice, just good, that's an example of a perfect answer ;)

Comment: Sorry and thank you. I solved the problem. I was doing 'pip install matplotlib' in a different directory. For some reason, I had two different directories 'Scripts', one of which contains pip and the other doesnt.

Comment: @JunJang, it's okay. Just consider this solution as an alternative. You probably are using virtual environments (not sure).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a package in pycharm, follow the instructions here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html